# I have an array of Circle objects and I need to fill a circle if it is clicked. How do I write the event handling for this?

Tags: java, javafx

```
//making the circles clickable
   circle[i].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
       @Override 
       public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
          
           
         circle[i].setFill(Color.BLUE);
          
       } 
    });
```

Is there any way to change the element at i without getting a "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for `MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html), you will see that it has a [`source`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#source) field that it inherits from [`EventObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html):

> The object on which the Event initially occurred.

So you can use this directly like so:

```
   circle[i].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
       @Override 
       public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
         ((Button)e.source).setFill(Color.BLUE);
       } 
    });
```

One point of advice: `setOnMouseClicked()` is a very low level event. Java provides other higher level events such as `ActionListener`. Using it is very similar. You can use this with `circle[i].setActionListener()` and override the `actionPerformed()` method. I suggest you read more about different listeners that are available so that you know which one to choose for a particular event.

Note: all links are for Java 7 documentation. Be sure to check the documentation for the version of Java which you are using.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I am not sure the `Button` cast is correct here. You also linked an `awt` JavaDoc.

Answer (score 2):

It should be enough to copy the variable i:

```java
// making the circles clickable
final int copyOfI = i;
circle[i].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
  @Override 
  public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
    circle[copyOfI].setFill(Color.BLUE);     
  } 
});
```

However, since the array can change later, I would copy the circle:

```java
final Circle c = circle[i];
c.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
  @Override 
  public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
    c.setFill(Color.BLUE);     
  } 
});
```